# Python: Passing a function with arguments as argument of another function

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments, callable

In the code below, inside WKB, I'm trying to pass the function "integrand" as an argument of the function int_gauss (like this: int_gauss(integrand(E,x0,m1,x),xp,wp)) and it returns me an error.

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
x0=1
m1=1
h=1
e=100


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def gaussxw(N):

    a = np.linspace(3,4*N-1,N)/(4*N+2)
    x = np.cos(np.pi*a+1/(8*N*N*np.tan(a)))

    # Find roots using Newton's method
    epsilon = 1e-15
    delta = 1.0
    while delta>epsilon:
        p0 = np.ones(N,float)
        p1 = np.copy(x)
        for k in range(1,N):
            p0,p1 = p1,((2*k+1)*x*p1-k*p0)/(k+1)
        dp = (N+1)*(p0-x*p1)/(1-x*x)
        dx = p1/dp
        x -= dx
        delta = max(abs(dx))

    # Calculate the weights
    w = 2*(N+1)*(N+1)/(N*N*(1-x*x)*dp*dp)

    return x,w

def gaussxwab(N,a,b):
    x,w = gaussxw(N)
    return 0.5*(b-a)*x+0.5*(b+a),0.5*(b-a)*w

N = 50
x, w = gaussxw(N)
 
def integrand(E,x0,m1,x):
    return    np.sqrt((2*m1*(E-    (e*( ((x0/x)**12) -2*((x0/x)**6)   )   ))))

def WKB(E,x0,e):
    a, b = x0*(1+np.sqrt(1+(E/e)))**(-1/6), x0*(1-np.sqrt(1+(E/e)))**(-1/6)
    xp = 0.5*(b - a)*x + 0.5*(b + a) 
    wp = 0.5*(b - a)*w  
    return int_gauss(integrand(E,x0,m1,x),xp,wp)

def int_gauss(f,nodes, weights):
  result = 0.0
  for x, w in zip(nodes, weights):
    result += w *f(x)
  return result



plt.close()
En=np.linspace(-100,-1,496)
W=[WKB(i,x0,e) for i in En]
plt.figure()
plt.plot(En,W)
plt.grid()
plt.axis()

plt.show()
```

I find the desired result when I explicitly compute the desired function "integrand" inside int_gauss like this but I'd like to be able to call int_gauss with the integrand function as a parameter int_gauss(integrand(E,x0,m1,x),xp,wp) inside WKB:

```
def WKB(E,x0,e):
    a, b = x0*(1+np.sqrt(1+(E/e)))**(-1/6), x0*(1-np.sqrt(1+(E/e)))**(-1/6)
    xp = 0.5*(b - a)*x + 0.5*(b + a) 
    wp = 0.5*(b - a)*w  
    return int_gauss(E,x0,m1,xp,wp)

def int_gauss(E,x0,m1,nodes, weights):
  result = 0.0
  for x, w in zip(nodes, weights):
    result += w * np.sqrt((2*m1*(E-    (e*( ((x0/x)**12) -2*((x0/x)**6)   )   ))))
  return result
```

Comment: See "functools.partial".

Comment: I tried     "return int_gauss(partial(integrand(E,x,1,1),xp,wp))" but it returns the error "TypeError: the first argument must be callable"

Comment: Placing parentheses after a function calls it immediately (but not in a lambda-expression) but you don't want this. I thought you wanted to integrate over the last parameter in "integrand". If  not, use lambda instead of "partial": `return int_gauss((lambda x: integrand(E,x,1,1)),xp,wp)`

Comment: I wanted to integrate over x, sorry if that was unclear. Thank you very much, your solution gives me the desired result as I wanted to write it even though I have not fully understood how it works yet.

Comment: "lambda" creates a function object which wraps the "integrand" function call to simplify it to a single parameter "x".